# How to properly configure apollo graphql + node.js to google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, graphql, google-cloud-sql, apollo-server

I am trying to deploy a node + apollo server to google app engine so that I can call https://appspot/graphql.  But I don't know how to achieve this.
https://localhost:8080/graphql runs successfully locally.  I can use as endpoint to query.
But https://appspot/graphql gives "GET query missing".
[image: file]

[image]
[image: file]

[image]

Problem solved by add playground:true, introspection: true to ApolloServer.  Also whitelist all network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen property any `modules` property, in Apollo Server config.

This is how I have setup my Apollo server:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
            schema: mySchema, //This contains my consolidate schema, for a basic 
                              //setup, it can be an object containing typedefs 
                              // and resolvers or 
                              //complex schema.
            context: context,  
            playground: {       //if we want to keep the playground on in 
                                //Production. By default it is disabled.
                enabled: true,
                settings: {
                  "request.credentials": "include"
                }
            }
});
```

Moreover we need to provide path like following:

```
server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/somepath' });
```

So if you are looking run your server at some path then, it can be setup like above.

Comment: module includes both schema and resolver.  It works locally so I assume it shouldn't cause any problem.  I think I also have connection issue with GAP to cloud sql.